# Best way to draw scrollmap

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, linear-gradients, processing.js

I want to draw a `scrollmap` on a `canvas` having a bunch of `Y` coordinates.

What is the most efficient to do so? I guess a gradient with some averaged points would be the best way, but I don't know how to do that.

What I'm thinking to do now is to fill the canvas with `red` and then draw `green` rectangle from top to each of the `Y` coordinate. If the rectangles have a certain degree of transparency that should result in a pretty decent-looking scroll heatmap.

Any other ideas? Or if someone knows how to implement the gradient one would be great.

If you don't know, a scrollmap should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: why use canvas for this, rather than a regular 100% height/width div with a css3 gradient background (http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ff3232+0,fcf528+20,30ff3a+40,30fffb+60,3041ff+80,ff00f6+100;Custom) and an opacity: 0.3 or something?

Comment: Well, wouldn't the `canvas` method be easier to code then to generate a cross-device `CSS3` gradient using javaScript? By using CSS gradient I have to replace the position of all the stop points, for all the browsers. I know that gradients or IE with more then 2 stop points are really buggy, especially if some of those points coincide. Good point though, I will try that too. (I asked for canvas because I already use canvas with heatmap.js , so the `canvas` is already there, I only have to draw a gradient on it...

Comment: Alsoo the real problem is `not` how to draw the gradient, but how to find the stop points for the gradient by having many `Y` heights.

Comment: it depends on what you want to target. do you have a list of "it should work in..." and "and ideally also in ..."? css3 gradients are easy in all current gen desktop browsers, for instance (ie10/11 will happily do multistop gradients). if your already have the canvas, it's a matter of finding the stops for RGB primaries+secondaries first, then doing simple interpolation (doing 255/0/0 to 255/255/0 to 0/255/0 in two simple lerps rather than complex color interpolation makes life easy)

Comment: Yes I know, but what's the most relevant and easy way to find those stop points? I was thinking about sorting the points ascending and then if I need 5 stops, get the values of Y of the 5 elements found at positions: 0, 1*NrY/5, 2*NrY/5, etc. in this sorted array. But this does not generate an accurate heatmap if lets say all Ys are the same  .

Comment: Do your Y coordinates represent stops already (if so, you'll always need four, for the yellow/green/cyan/blue stops. red and magenta are automatic at 0% and 100%)? If not, what do they represent?

Comment: It's a scrollmap. Each 'Y' represents how down did each visitor scroll. If you have 1 milion users you will have one million `Y`s. I need to compress this one million `Y`s into a 4-5 gradient stops.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the additional information from the comments, you probably want to use a binning approach. If we slice up the page into *X* height regions (each region having a height of *1/X* times pageheight) then we can simply perform a tally based on which "bin" a user's final scroll height fell into. In JSesque pseudocode:

```
var X = 5, bins = [], idx;
userScrollHeights.forEach(function(Y) {
  idx = Math.floor(map(Y, 0, pageHeight, 0, X));
  bins[id] = bins[idx] ? bins[idx]++ : 1;
});
```

The mapping function is curiously missing from the standard JS API but is easily implemented as:

```
function map(value, istart, istop, ostart, ostop) {
  return ostart + (ostop - ostart) * ((value - istart) / (istop - istart));
}
```

The bins array now contains the "intensity" of each bin. The more bins you pick, the more accurate your scrollmap will be.

Of course, the basic scrollmap is not colored, it's simply intensity, so it's more naturally a white-to-black overlay. If you really want a colored map, with "most intense" mapping to red, and "least intense" mapping to violet, you could use a setup with 255 bins, and simply map each intensity level to a color value, after finding the maximum intensity:

```
var bin_max = 0;
bins.forEach(function(value) {
  if(value > bin_max) bin_max= value;
});
```

followed by a color mapping based on the five slices in a "rainbow" gradient:

```
function mapIntensityToColor(intensity, min, max) {
  var cint = map(intensity,min,max,0,255);
  var step = (max - min) / 5;
  if(cint > 204) 
    return [255, map(intensity, max-step,max, 255,0), 0];
  if(cint > 153) 
    return [map(intensity, max-2*step,max-step, 0,255), 255, 0];
  if(cint > 102) 
    return [0, 255, map(intensity, max-3*step,max-2*step, 255,0)];
  if(cint > 51)
    return [0, map(intensity, max-4*step,max-3*step, 0,255), 255];
  return [map(intensity, min,max-4*step, 255,0), 0, 255];
}
```

Segmenting your canvas (or div) in 255 steps and coloring each step based on `mapIntensityToColor(bin[step_number], 0, bin_max)` should now give you an accurate scroll map.

Comment: I implemented your sudo code in javascript and the `mapIntensityToColor` function giving me values like `[-1020.0000000000002, 0, 255]` . you can see the value of red is negative and not between 0 to 255, how to solve this?

Comment: this wasn't pseudo-code, this was already Javascript, you shouldn't have had to change a single letter for it to work. What input did you use for the `mapIntensityToColor` function?

Comment: If the bin array [11, 7, 0, 0,.....,0] and bin_max = 11, so first `mapIntensityToColor` function should call like `mapIntensityToColor(11, 0, 11)` and gives output `[-1020.0000000000005, 0, 255]`

Comment: ah, looks like the code was forgetting to remap the initial `intensity`. Fixed that.

Comment: Can you tell me little bit more about this `map` function? I'm just curious what could be the logic behind this function and how its related to `mapIntensityToColor` function. I want to know what was your thoughts or approach to solve this problem.